# Duplicate identical fields between ServiceStack's UserOAuthProvider and UserAuth tables

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

Is there a particular reason why these fields are duplicated with the same data across the UserOAuthProvider and UserAuth tables?

```
UserName: someusername,
Email: "someusername@somedomain.com",
PrimaryEmail: "",
FirstName: null,
LastName: null,
DisplayName: "",
BirthDate: null,
BirthDateRaw: null,
Country: null,
Culture: "en",
FullName: "",
Gender: null,
Language: null,
MailAddress: "",
Nickname: null,
PostalCode: null,
TimeZone: null,
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `UserAuth` table is the parent record that holds the master data for the user which gets merged every time a user authenticates with an external provider whilst the `UserOAuthProvider` tables holds the information about the user that was gathered for a single auth provider after the user logs in.

Comment: Did a simple test and it appears all fields get merged except for DisplayName which seems to keep the very original value when the record was first created. Do you know if this is by design?

Comment: @Val yeah it is, there are reserved fields for functional fields like UserName, DisplayName and Email which needs to be explicitly updated.